# How to handle static frameworks dependencies

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries, static-linking, ios-frameworks

I am trying to build Objective-C static frameworks but ran into hierarchy/organization problems.

For the question, assume I have 3 classes, classA, classB, and classC. classB and classC are children classes of classA. classB and classC each needs special resource files.

```
#import "classB.h"
#import "classC.h"
@implement classA

  + (classA)factoryMethodCreateType:(NSString *)type {
      classA a;
      if ([type isEqualToString:@"classB"]) {
        a = [[classB alloc] init];
      } else if ([type isEqualToString:@"classC"]) {
        a = [classC alloc] init];
      }
      return a;
  }

@end
```

I'd like to statically package the frameworks, classB.framework and classC.framework, such that when a user wants to use classB, they don't need to include classC and its resource files. Additionally, the user can use classA as the entry point to use either of the frameworks.

I assume if I just create classB.framework (includes classA and classB) and classC.framework (includes classA and classC), when the user wants to use both types and include both frameworks, the user will face duplicate symbols?

What is the best way to handle this situation? Is the following approach the best way to do it?

Change classA's implementation to dynamic creation of classB or classC and not include their header files.

Build 3 frameworks instead of 2: classA.framework, classB.framework, classC.framework. When the user wants to use classB, the the user should include both classA.framework and classB.framework.

```
@implement classA
+ (classA)factoryMethodCreateType:(NSString *)type {
    classA a;

    id obj = [NSClassFromString(type) alloc];
    a = objc_msgSend(obj, @selector(init));
    return a;
}

@end
```

Comment: It sounds like you're creating problems that don't really exist.  Assuming frameworks B and C have no cross-dependencies, you can just create 3 frameworks.  Users of A will have to import B and/or C, depending on which they end up using, but either way, each framework is only added to the project once.

Comment: Static frameworks do not contain resources, they only contain header files and a binary. Resources can come in bundles or a single files, alongside with the framework.